# Protect vb module through pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba, pywin32

I have written python script using pywin32 package to create macro enabled excel workbook and add vb module to it. I have assigned this vb module sub to a macro button. I want to lock the vb module from viewing by users but still should be functional. Is there any way that I can do it in pywin32 or other package in python.

SendKeys needs to have VBEditor open containing that module in order to lock the project from viewing. I don't want excel application to be visible while it locks the project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.